# Postgres - Subtraction of two queries

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to make a subtraction like this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(column1))) AS distance_km 
     FROM table1) - 
    (SELECT ST_Y(ST_Transform(column1,4326)) AS distance_km 
     FROM table1) AS Difference
```

But the `ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(column1)))` has only one row and `ST_Y(ST_Transform(column1,4326))` has multiple rows. I want to subtract the multiple rows by the column and see the results for each multiple row. With this query I get:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Any help?

Comment: Please show an example case.  Are you suggesting that if you have `10` from the first query, and `{1,2,5,7}` from the second query, you want the results `{9,8,5,3}`?

Comment: Same with `SELECT (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2);`. You just can't do this with SQL!

Comment: @MikeT - "You" can't use the syntax used by the Op, correct.  But, depending on the Op's actual ***functional*** requirement, SQL most likely *is* able to full-fill it, with the correct syntax.

Comment: @MatBailie yes it's that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following query will join a one-row result set against a many row result set, and allow them to be compared.

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*,
    a.distance_km - b.distance_kn    AS difference
FROM
(
    SELECT  ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(column1))) AS distance_km FROM table1
)
    a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT ST_Y(ST_Transform(column1,4326)) AS distance_km FROM table1
)
    b
```

Comment: @PRVS - Sub-queries and `CROSS JOIN` are ANSI-SQL.  So, yes, it works in PostGreSQL.

Comment: @MatBailie: the name is either spelled PostgreSQL or just Postgres. Never with a capital G